# Reuse the Primefaces Dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces, dialog

I have a Primefaces JSF view myView.xhtml with a form (with id 'myformID') and datatable (with id 'myDataTableId') in it. I also have a dialog box (myDialog.xhtml). I am including the myDialog.xhtml in myView.xhtml. When we click on the commandButton in 'myDialog.xhtml', it will update a datatable after executing the method specified in action listener. I am updating the datatable with update=":myFormId:myDataTableId"and it is working fine.

But I would like to use the same dialog in different view. The form id and datatable id are different in that view. So, how can I reuse the dialog and update datatables with different id's (currently I am creating one more dialog by duplicating the code and changed the value in the update attribute of commandButton accordingly)?

Comment: You can create a JSF composite component for the dialog. Very good example of how to implement a composite component is in following blog entry by mkyong: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/composite-components-in-jsf-2-0/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass parameters with `ui:include` example :

**master.xhtml**

```
<ui:include src="include.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="customId" value="4567" />
</ui:include>
```

**include.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition>
    <p:dialog id="#{customId}" ...>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```